# C# Routine firing on time

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

I has a numericUpDown called nud.
nud=0.5, min 0.5, max 6 and increment 0.5.
This nud is the time interval that my routine to be executed.
If nud==0.5, my routine to run every 30 minutes; if nud==1, run every 1 hour; nud==1.5, run every 1 hour and 30 minutes(90 minutes) and so on.
However, if nud nud==0.5||1.5||2.5||3.5||4.5||5.5, the routine should be triggered when the system clocks is like this HH:00:00 or HH:30:00.(every half hour)

If nud==1||2||3||4||5||6, the routine should be triggered when the system clocks is like this HH:00:00 (full hour).

Every tip, idea, link is welcome.
Thanks in advance,
ocaccy

Comment: With `nud==0.5||1.5||2.5||3.5||4.5||5.5`, are all but the first specification (0.5) redundant?

Comment: Thank you Will A. if nud==0.5, the timer routine will be 30 minutes and the routine will be shot in the next half hour. If nud==1, the timer routine will be 1 hour and the routine will be triggered in the next hour. If nud==1.5, the timer routine will be 1 hour and 30 minutes and the routine will be triggered in the next 1 hour and 30 minutes and so on.

Comment: @JeffB. I tried like this: seconds=DateTime.Now.Second; minutes=DateTime.Now.Minute; hour=(DateTime.Now.Hour); adjsec=60-(seconds); if(Convert.ToDouble(nud.Value)==0.5) { if(minutes<30) { adjmin=30-((minutes)+1); } else { adjmin=60-((minutes)+1); } } else if(Convert.ToDouble(nud.Value)==1) { adjmin=60-((minutes)+1); } ... But now I'm testing timespan. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: What type of application is this? Console? WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Silverlight? Something else?

Comment: Also, Your spec is incomplete.  What do you want to do initially? Say `nud == 0.5` and you start the application at 3:10.  Do you fire right away or not? Do you fire at 3:30? Or wait until 4:00?

Comment: WinForms! I need to know the time between the click on the start button and the next full hour or half hour according the nud. For example if the nud=1.5; the timer.interval=90000, the timer.start() after 90 minutes + the difference between the click and the next full hour or half hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ~think~ you want something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private DateTime dt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetInitialTimer();
    }

    private void SetInitialTimer()
    {
        // Set "dt" to the BEGINNING of the CURRENT hour:
        dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, 0, 0);

        switch (nud.Value.ToString())
        {
            case "0.5":
            case "1.5":
            case "2.5":
            case "3.5":
            case "4.5":
            case "5.5":
                // start at the NEXT 1/2 hour or top of the hour:
                if (DateTime.Now.Minute < 30)
                {
                    dt = dt.AddMinutes(30);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = dt.AddHours(1);
                }
                break;

            default: // "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
                // start at the TOP of the NEXT hour:
                dt = dt.AddHours(1);
                break;

        }

        timer1.Interval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        // ... do something in here ...

        SetRecurringTimer();
    }

    private void SetRecurringTimer()
    {
        dt = dt.AddMinutes((double)(nud.Value * (decimal)60));
        timer1.Interval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: The app was a bit more complicated. Now we have another numericUpDown called nud_minusMinutes minimum 1 and maximum 29. The timer1.Inteval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds will be minus nud_minusMinutes and if the timer1.Interval will be greater than nud_minusMinutes.Value start in the next half hour if nud.Value ==0.5 and nud.Value>=1 in the next full hour.

Answer (score 2):

"The app was a bit more complicated. Now we have another numericUpDown called nud_minusMinutes minimum 1 and maximum 29. The timer1.Inteval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds will be minus nud_minusMinutes and if the timer1.Interval will be greater than nud_minusMinutes.Value start in the next half hour if nud.Value ==0.5 and nud.Value>=1 in the next full hour."

Modified code to address new requirements:

```
    private void SetRecurringTimer()
    {
        /*
         * The timer1.Inteval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds will be minus nud_minusMinutes 
         * and if the timer1.Interval will be greater than nud_minusMinutes.Value 
         * start in the next half hour if nud.Value ==0.5 
         * and nud.Value>=1 in the next full hour that fits the timer1.Interval. 
         */

        dt = dt.AddMinutes((double)(nud.Value * (decimal)60));

        DateTime adjustedDT = dt.AddMinutes((int)(-1 * nud_minusMinutes.Value));
        int interval = (int)adjustedDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        double adjustment = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)nud_minusMinutes.Value).TotalMilliseconds;

        if (interval > adjustment)
        {
            if (nud.Value == (decimal)0.5)
            {
                dt = dt.AddMinutes(30); // next 1/2 hour
            }
            else
            {
                // next full hour
                if (dt.Minute == 0)
                {
                    dt = dt.AddHours(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = dt.AddMinutes(30);
                }
            }
            timer1.Interval = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Interval = (int)adjustedDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect. 
I found that we need to put this in SetInitialTimer.
Because, why nud_minusMinutes (>)is greater than the time of the click until the next half or full hour, (-) less nud_minusMinutes, we have a negative.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do it would be to have a trigger that fires every second and check the values (is minute 30 and second 0).